# How to do addition in a batch file using numbers set in text files

Tags: batch-file, addition

I want to set a text file to a specific number, and then add it to the number stated in the batch file.

```
:opt21
cls
echo Account Balance
echo _______________________________________________________
type "C:\Users\Accounts\%log%.%pas%\bal.txt"
pause
goto login
:opt23
cls
set /a lab=<C:\Users\Accounts\%log%.%pas%\bal.txt
echo Account Deposit
echo _______________________________________________________
set /p da=Deposit Ammount (In $):
set /a tda= %lab% + %da%
:setop
cls
echo Account Deposit
echo _______________________________________________________
echo Your new balance will be $%tda%, continue?
set /p yn2=(Y/N):
if "%yn2%"=="Y" goto tda
if "%yn2%"=="N" goto opt21
cls
echo Sorry, "%yn2%" is not valid.
pause
goto setop
:tda
cls
del /F /Q "C:\Users\Accounts\%log%.%pas%\bal.txt"
break >"C:\Users\Accounts\%log%.%pas%\bal.txt"
echo %tda% >>"C:\Users\Accounts\%log%.%pas%\bal.txt"
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo .
echo                  New Balance Set
timeout /t 2 >nul /nobreak
cls
goto opt21
```

What it's supposed to do is take the number that is inside of C:\Users\Accounts\%log%.%pas%\bal.txt and add it to the number specified by the user in the variable "%da%", what it does currently is take the number specified by the user in the variable "%da%" and makes that the number in the file, it doesn't add it at all, it just replaces it.

Comment: `set /a lab=<C:\Users\Accounts\%log%.%pas%\bal.txt` has to be `set /p` Only `set /p` will accept redirected input. You should consider using `choice.exe` for the y/n input.

Comment: Just a hint, `set /A ` doesn't require to enclose variables in percent signs. `set /a tda=lab+da` will do.

Comment: Another hint: It is always recommended to quote `set /a` and `set /p`.

Comment: I know set /A doesn't require enclose variables, it's just a habbit

Comment: Do you know that `set /p` comes with a hazard? If the input is `1==1" & format D:\ & echo`. It can format your drive.